# How can I update an external list connected to SQL?

Tags: sql-server, external-list

I am working with Project Server 2010 and SQL Server 2008.  I would like to create a multiple item form that connects to SQL Server.

I tried using an external list in SharePoint that connects to SQL.  The records were displayed in a multiple item view in SPD 2010, but I was not able to update the list. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please checkout this video. It has a demonstration of the functionality you are looking for: http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/consuming-external-data-with-business-connectivity-services-in-sharepoint-2010/10tmc8guo